# "This area is too big to download" from the Planet Explorer plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, download, india

I am trying to get a satellite image for the entire of India in March 2020. When I had first installed the Planet_Explorer plugin and put in my criteria, I was able to see all the base maps for the period. However, now I keep getting this message:

> This area is too big to download from the QGIS Plugin. To download a
> large Basemap area, you may want to consult our developer resources

I had also put this into the XYZ tiles, but I am not sure it is showing there either. Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you asking how the Plugin works, or are you asking how/where to get the image you want, or are you asking how to use the Plugin with XYZ tiles? Which resolution should the image have? Which data source do you prefer? Which channels are you interested in?

Comment: This is the first time I am using the plugin, so almost everything is unclear to me at this stage. I understand how to get the base maps, when I tried this earlier, the base maps worked just fine. However now when I try to get base maps for the AOI of the entire India boundary, it says that the area selected is too large. I don't understand why it worked then, but isn't now. 
Resolution: 300m. 
Landsat images.
I also would like to know how to use it with the XYZ tiles.

Comment: What prevents you from using the Landsat [download HP](https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/nli/landsat/landsat-data-access?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#qt-science_support_page_related_con)?

Answer (score 7):

On June 15 2021, a [download limit](https://github.com/planetlabs/qgis-planet-plugin/blob/master/planet_explorer/gui/pe_basemaps_widget.py#L72) was added to the plugin.

[image]

I'm not sure if it works, but you may increase the limit by increasing `MAX_AREA_TO_DOWNLOAD` value.

- In QGIS go to `Settings > User Profiles > Open Active Profile Folder`
- Navigate to `python/plugins/planet_explorer/gui`
- Open `pe_basemaps_widget.py` file
- Increase `MAX_AREA_TO_DOWNLOAD` value.

Comment: There's probably a reason for this limit, though. It would be good to understand why it was added in the first place, and to check if it's possible to download the data in smaller chunks, with enough pause inbetween.

Comment: @EricDuminil You are absolutely right. It’s just an urgent and temporary solution.